# JQuery - How do you jump between to javascript pages?

Tags: jquery, text

I am trying my hand once again at making a game via JQuery, and I am stuck trying to move between a text based console game and a clicker game. I have 2 .js files, one that houses the text based code and another to house the button masher.

I can get much of it to work, but I can't get the clicker game to go back to the form to pass back into the text based game.

For the text based game I have a script as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#console").fadeIn(3000); //A console to keep everything looking good
    $("form").submit(function() { //User input
    var input = $("#command_line").val(); //A nifty box to put your answers in
    //As you answer questions, the messages auto scroll
    $('#console').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
)};
```

For the clicker side:

```
function warrior() {
    $('#console').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
    swung = (swung + swungPower);
    document.getElementById('swung').innerHTML = swung;
    if (boardHP != 0) {
        boardHP = (boardHP - swungPower);
        document.getElementById('boardHP').innerHTML = boardHP;
    }
    else {
        $("<p>The board broke, lets set up a new one.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        boardHP = 100;
        document.getElementById('boardHP').innerHTML = boardHP;
        money++;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
        $("<p>You now have $" + money + ".</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        Age++;
        document.getElementById("Age").innerHTML = Age;
        Str = Str + 3;
        document.getElementById("Str").innerHTML = Str;
        Def = Def + 2;
        document.getElementById("Def").innerHTML = Def;
        if (Age >= 25) {
            if (x.style.display === "inline-block") {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
            $("<p>You are now old enough to go into battle, would you like to go to battle? y or n.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            //At this point the code should jump back inside game.js, but it doesn't want to.
            if (input == "y" || input == "Y" || input == "Yes" || input == "yes") {
                if (i.style.display === "none") {
                    i.style.display = "inline-block";
                    area = "Battle";
                    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = area;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the 'if (input == yes)' it's supposed to open another div, but it doesn't. I can tell, both because the other div doesn't show and the area doesn't change. I have tried many things, but I cannot get it to go. $('#console').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow'); allows text to show up in the console, but not on this last part. I can't get this on my own, nor can I find anything on what I'm asking.

Comment: If someone can, at least, point me to a similar question on here, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to plug my battle system back into my main java script page to get it to start up. It simply would not start inside my Clicker java script page.